# Printing json data in react js

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to print Json data in React-js, but It prints with quotes and brackets like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPXxO.png).
Here's my react-js code:

```
return (             
targets.map(targets => (
<div key={targets.type}>
  <h1>{targets.type}:</h1>
  <p key={targets.data}>{targets.data}</p>
 </div>
  )))
```

And json data:
      [json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbIKP.png)

I tried to make same in jquery and it worked with this code:

```
targets=[];
key=[];               
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
targets.push(results["targets"][i]["type"]);
key.push(JSON.parse(results["targets"][i]["data"]));
$.each(key[i], function (index, value) {
$(".keys").prepend('<p>'+(index+":"+value)+'</p>');
});
$(".keys").prepend('<h3>'+targets[i]+':</h3>');
}
```

Comment: do you want to print it as a JSON or just the values?

Comment: I want to print the keys and values of every type like this range_to: 18  , range_from: 4 etc..

Comment: Could you share the JSON

Comment: it's added in the text but here's the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbIKP.png

Comment: I used it like this with no problem  https://codesandbox.io/s/21o2n1p52j

Comment: Check that and let me know :)

Comment: I have object in my data so it doesn't work with this https://codesandbox.io/embed/z6m3wvv6wx

Comment: Maybe you want to render it like in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-render-json-example). The switch inside the `LocationItem` is just to have more control about how each data entry gets rendered.

Comment: Something like that just wihout checkboxes , but thank you I used your code!

Answer (score 0):

Since `target.data` is String you will need to parse it.

Something like this should do the trick

```
 getData(data) {
   return (
      Object.keys(data).map(key => <span value={key}>{`${key}:${data[key]}`}</span>)
)}

return (             
   targets.map(targets => (
        <div key={targets.type}>
            <h1>{targets.type}:</h1>
            <p key={targets.data}>getData(JSON.parse(targets.data))}</p>
        </div>)))
```